# Pymongo - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, database, pymongo, robo3t

Here the code where I am facing an error:

```
machine1 = {
                'Entry1': Entry1.get_value(),
                'Exit1': Exit1.get_value(),
                'id': 'test'
                }
result = Machine1.insert_one(machine1)
db.machine1.updateOne(
    {"Entry1": 'true'},('$set' : {"Entry1": Entry1.get_value()}, {upsert : True})

)
userId = result.inserted_id
```

> ```
>  {"Entry1": 'true'},('$set' : {"Entry1": Entry1.get_value()}, {upsert : True})
>                                ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Above is the error
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: `{('$set' : {"Entry1": Entry1.get_value()}}`  wrap with `{}`

Comment: still an invalid syntax sir

Comment: Could you provide the update line